# How to import data in bulk on redis-stack-server from a .rdb file?

Tags: python, redis, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am running [redis-stack](https://redis.io/docs/stack/) on [wsl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about).

TLDR - Redis stack isn't able to pick up data from the persisted .rdb file and keeps pointing to in memory records..

I have a pipeline that appends my [dataframes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to the redis stack db.

As soon as I run this pipeline , a `dump.rdb` file gets stored at `\\wsl.localhost\wsl-base\home\wsluser\redis-stack-server-6.2.6-v7\var\db\redis-stack`

I need to run this pipeline on 3 different datasets and utilize each `dump.rdb` at a later stage.

Problem - If I replace `dump.rdb`(from dataset 1) by `dump.rdb`(from dataset 2) at `\\wsl.localhost\wsl-base\home\wsluser\redis-stack-server-6.2.6-v7\var\db\redis-stack` , redis stack is **not loading** from the `dump.rdb`(from dataset 2) and still points to `dump.rdb`(from dataset 1). I have alread already tried the below:

- Restart redis stack server
- Empty the db by flushall and then replace the `dump.rdb`

According to the [documentation for redis](https://developer.redis.com/guides/import/), the "The file dump.rdb is automatically imported.". But mind you, this is for redis and not redi-stack